# Frontend html components in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, structure

I am trying to organize my code structure for a new project. I am creating module patterns for each javascript file as shown below:

> **core.js**

```
var core = (function(){
     // private functions
     var privateFunc = function(){

     },
     privateFuncTwo = function(){

     };

     // public functions
     return {
          publicFunc: function(){

          },
          publicFuncTwo: function(){

          }
     };
})();
```

> **Code Structure**

```
Project
    -- js
       -- core
           -- components.js  // Has all the html components
           -- core.js        // defines core methods to use like ajax, event bindings.. using jquery.js
           -- sandbox.js     // refers core.js and components.js to make methods to use 
       -- plugins
           -- jquery.js
    -- skins
       -- css
           -- main.css
           -- normalize.css
       -- images
           -- logo.png
    -- app.js    // uses sandbox.js and jquery.js
    -- index.html
```

Architecture decided to keep the HTML components in client side. So, I am keeping the HTML components in Client side in a js file `components.js` as shown below:

```
var components = (function(){
    return {
        section: function(){
            return '<div class="section">\
                        <div class="section-header">\
                            <div class="section-title">\
                                {{title}}\
                            </div>\
                            <div class="section-link">\
                                <a href="{{link}}">{{linkName}}</a>\
                            </div>\
                        </div>\
                        <div class="section-body">\
                            \
                        </div>\
                    </div>';
        }
    }
})();
```

I am just confused whether this is better way or not..

and also please help me to decide the plugins to use the code in structure.

For Information, I am using node.js as server language.

Comment: Looks like you might be trying to build your own `angularJS` :)

Comment: @BenWilde ohh is it so? I don't know angularjs..

Comment: https://angularjs.org/